# Adding variable to the end of a simple xml call

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

ok below is my code, to call an external xml file and return some information in xml format, now this works perfectly if i manually add the value to the end of the url string, however as soon as i replace the value with the variable $reg it doesn't return any results.

```
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$file = 'http://testsite.mywebsite.co.uk/app.xml?apikey=*******************&vid=TEST&vrm=$reg';
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
 exit('Failed to open '.$file);
print_r($xml);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, as i can not see why it wouldn't work, i have even tried wrapping it in quotes, but still nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Use double quotes for the string, rather than single quotes. Or concatenate `$reg` onto it.  The variable `$reg` can only be interpolated inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: echo $file just after you set it, that way you will see what the url you are requesting is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$file = 'http://testsite.mywebsite.co.uk/app.xml?pikey=*******************&vid=TEST&vrm='.$reg;
echo "Filename: " . $file; // < --- added this so that you can check the filename is correct
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)){
 exit('Failed to open '.$file);
}
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes if you want PHP to parse variables within your string:

```
$file = "http://testsite.mywebsite.co.uk/app.xml?apikey=*******************&vid=TEST&vrm=$reg";
```